# How to place hanging icon in upper right corner of Card composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, iconbutton

How can I achieve the effect shown below in the picture on a `Card` composable, with the `X` icon, for instance, hanging in the upper right corner? I don't want the rounded corners nor the black background, just the icon hanging in the upper right corner of the `Card`. I couldn't achieve this despite several attempts.

[image]

**Original Code on SO**

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(LightGray)
        .padding(16.dp)
        .size(88.dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd
) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(
            id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
        ),
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.Center)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            .background(Black)
            .size(80.dp),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    )
    IconButton(
        onClick = {},
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(White)
            .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
            .size(16.dp)
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Close,
            contentDescription = "",
        )
    }
}
```

**Possible Code Structure?**

```
Box(...) {

    Card(...) {
        Image(...) {
        }
    }
    
    IconButton(...) {
        Icon(...) {
        }
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in many ways. One of them is using Modifier.offset{}, another one using Modifier.graphicsLayer{} and setting translationX and translationY params, or `Layout` that places your Icon based on Image Composables.

```
@Composable
private fun MyIconBox() {

    val iconSize = 24.dp
    val offsetInPx = LocalDensity.current.run { (iconSize / 2).roundToPx() }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding((iconSize / 2))) {

        Card {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape4),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
            )
        }

        IconButton(
            onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset {
                    IntOffset(x = +offsetInPx, y = -offsetInPx)
                }
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .background(White)
                .size(iconSize)
                .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Close,
                contentDescription = "",
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: For Alignment.TopStart for IconButton, you can do following:                             .offset { IntOffset(x = -offsetInPx, y = -offsetInPx) }